# R Shiny send login data to database connection

Tags: r, shiny

I have an application that runs a SAP MDX query to get data to Shiny for generating some charts. In SAP every query is executed with specific user rights so every user should login. What I need is a login form in ui.R that will send data to connect statement, so I need pass USER and PASSWORD variables to the connection command:

```
con <- RMDX(url=URL, uid = USER, pwd = PASSWORD)
```

Any suggestion? I need a Javascript popup.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your own login form using [passwordInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/passwordInput.html) for example.  I've also used the package [getPass](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/getPass/index.html) for getting username/password from the commandline in R.  I don't know if that would be able to integrate with Shiny though.

Comment: I can' t use none of this because my service runs in a Docker container, user will access a link and they can see only the web interface. So I need a Javascript popup.